# How to draw a horizontal histogram graph base on value in database with php?

Tags: php, html

I have problem on drawing an histogram base on my marks that I store in database. I found number of example and it won't work for my database.

Here is how my database look like:

```
mark |task |student |subject|
--------------------------------
20     A1   Chris1   CHEM123
10     A1   David    CHEM123
```

...and more

I wanted to view the mark from the particular task.
And the output is similar like this:

```
 0
 2
 4
 6 *****
 8 ************
10 *****
12 ****************
14 *********
16 ****
18 ***
20
22
24
26
28
```

But I've failed to do so. I failed to show out output similar with that.

Here is the example code I found (index.php):

```
$data = array (
            'Column 1' => 8,
            'Column 2' => 5,
            'Column 3' => 8,
            'Column 4' => 5,
            'Column 5' => 8,
            'Column 6' => 6,
            'Column 7' => 7,
            'Column 8' => 8,
            'Column 9' => 9,
            'Column 10' => 8,
            'Column 11' => 12,
            'Column 12' => 4,
            'Column 13' => 2
            );
$max = max($data);
echo '<table>';
foreach ($data as $k=>$v)
{
    echo "<tr><td>$k</td><td><img src='bar.php?max=$max&val=$v'> $v</td></tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Here is the bar.php:

```
<?php
// set dimensions
$w     = 202;
$h     = 20;
// create image
$im    = imagecreate($w, $h);
// set colours to be used
$bg    = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xE0, 0xE0, 0xE0);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
$red   = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
$green = imagecolorallocate($im, 0x50, 0xB6, 0x30);
// draw border
imagerectangle($im, 0, 0, $w - 1, $h - 1, $bg); // border uses background colur also
imagecolortransparent($im, $bg); // now make bg colour transparent
// get value and max value from query string
$val  = isset($_GET['val']) ? $_GET['val'] : 0;
$max  = isset($_GET['max']) ? $_GET['max'] : 100;
// calculate dimensions of inner bar
$barw = $max ? floor(($w - 2) * $val / $max) : 0;
$barh = $h - 2;
// draw inner bar
if ($barw) {
    $barcolor = $red;
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 1, 1, $barw, $barh, $barcolor);
}
// send image header
header("content-type: image/png");
// send png image
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved with a javascript library such as [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). It gets you nice, fancy and easy to use graphs, you just need to define the data the way you already did, but in js.

#### EDITED

Highcharts is a library of javascript code that will draw charts for you, just add the library to your page. The [documentation](http://docs.highcharts.com/#home) is fairly clear to follow. To add it to your page it just put these lines in the `<head>` section:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Then add this row of code, which define where to draw the chart `<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>`. You can change the width and height to fit your needs.

Now just pass your data to the graph adding the following code (it's an extract from the documentation to draw a simple chart) to your page:

```
<script>
$(function () { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});​
</script>
```

I presume the code is self-explanatory, you can define the chart type (bar), the title,X and Y axis and the series of data. You should put your data in an array, each number in the array will be a bar in your chart.

Comment: Mate, thanks for the answer. But i'm just a beginner, i don't really understand how is the concept yet. Mind to guide me? Thanks

Comment: Mate, then how i supporse to store my data in order to draw the graph?

Comment: Mate, how to create a php value in order to add in the data for title,x and y axis?

Comment: If should use a variable, but if your data are static (always the same) you can embedd them in the code: `title: { text: 'Your title here'}`

Comment: did u mean like title:{ text: <?php some php ode here?>} ?